# BlackBerry Webworks app crash with blank alert box - How to debug?

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-widgets, blackberry-webworks

I've created a BlackBerry webworks application that consists of multiple pages each loading data from a local SQLite database.

The application works fine until I've navigated between a certain number of pages, at which time the application shows a blank alert box and hangs on the loading screen that shows between pages.

This is using the Bold 9700 simulator but also occurs on the device itself. I've tried disabling caching, as well as increasing the size of the cache, both to no avail. The console shows nothing, neither does the event log on the simulator.

Has anyone come across this behaviour before? More importantly, how do I get any useful debug information out of the simulator so I can track down the culprit?

Many thanks!

**Edit:** I've tracked this down the the html5_init.js library that Blackberry recommend for translating HTML5 to Google Gears calls for OS5. Any ideas?

**Further Edit:** I've removed all traces of html5_init.js and instead I'm using the Google Gears API directly. This resolves the problem but requires that I double up all my database code. Google Gears requires that you call clear() on all ResultSets so that they don't cause a memory leak but html5_init doesn't offer that functionality. Maybe that could be the cause?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what was happening, but the blank alert box is likely the result of something that should have shown a value, but the content was an empty string. e.g. `var foo = '';alert(foo);` its likely not intentional that foo is blank thus whenever I add alert messages I always add a static string prefix: `alert('foo: ' + foo);` so that i can tell if foo is blank.  As for the reason the html5_init.js shim isn't working I'm not sure.